# Is there a way to avoid computing the inverse in the problem $\mathbf{y}=AB^{-1}\mathbf{x}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, python

I'm writing some code in Python that has to deal with very large matrices so it is virtually impossible (atleast very sub-optimal) to compute inverses of matrices. In an earlier problem I ran into a situation where i had $\mathbf{y}=A^{-1}B\mathbf{x}$ where $A$ and $B$ are large square matrices and $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are vectors. I could turn this into $A\mathbf{y}=B\mathbf{x}$ and then solve for $\mathbf{y}$. However, I'm not sure how to eliminate computing the inverse in the problem described in the title, i.e. if I have $\mathbf{y}=AB^{-1}\mathbf{x}$. Figured it would be fine to post this question here since it's not so much programming related and more linear algebra related.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Set $z=B^{-1}x$ and solve $Bz=x$, $y=Az$.

Comment: Also, why should $B$ be invertible, take $B=0$. Same with $A$ in $y=A^{-1}Bx$.

Comment: @J.G. It doesn't. In the text I explain how I avoided the inverse $\mathbf{y}=A^{-1}B\mathbf{x}$ and now I want to know how to avoid computing the inverse in \mathbf{y}=AB^{-1}\mathbf{x}.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Perhaps I should have added it, but the problem is assuming that A and B are both sparse non-singular matrices.

Comment: @A.Γ. That looks like it'll do the trick. Thanks alot.